# How does Crafter Delivery pull from Studio’s published local git repo remotely?

Tags: crafter-cms

Referring to the 2nd diagram in this page:

https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.0/developers/architecture.html
or
https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.0/_images/detailed.png

specifically the arrow from Delivery to Authoring. Here I assume Deliver and Authoring does ***not*** share any file system.

In crafter-deployer configuration for Delivery, what is the syntax for the url setting shown in this yaml example?

https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.0/system-administrators/deployer/admin-guide.html#target-configuration

Answer (score 0):

It's a repository path/url to a valid the site's (published) Git repository on the authoring server.

If both authoring and delivery are on the same machine (simple deployments, developer machines, PoC's etc) this is just a file path.

In "real-world" deployments such as production and lower environments authoring and delivery are typically installed in separate machines. This you need a URL/path that points to the authoring server.  Typically over SSH.  It's secure and simple.
Example:

> ssh://myserver/opt/crater/sites/mysite

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols

The best way to configure the deployer on the delivery instance is to use the init-site executable.
https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.0/system-administrators/activities/setup-site-for-delivery.html

Comment: To clarify, you have ONE authoring server and multiple delivery servers and each delivery server is just doing SSH file transfers of a published folder inside the git repo that is checked out on that single authoring server's filesystem?